# Get the level/number of iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have a website with iframe with a site with another iframe, so it is one iframe inside another iframe(all on different domains). So is there a way to get the number of all iframes or some props from parent div or the url of the parent main div (parent->child iframe->child iframe).

thanks

Comment: No. Not at all possible as soon as you cross origins

Answer (score 1):

You can't access an iFrame content on different domain, is a XSS protection issue.

Comment: I don't think this is true anymore

Comment: It is still true, you must have control on the iframe domain and externak code in order to exchange messages, the question mentioned "parent div or the url of the parent main div (parent->child iframe->child iframe)"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the new window.postMessage() API - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

> The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin communication. Normally, scripts on different pages are allowed to access each other if and only if the pages that executed them are at locations with the same protocol (usually both https), port number (443 being the default for https), and host (modulo Document.domain being set by both pages to the same value). window.postMessage() provides a controlled mechanism to circumvent this restriction in a way which is secure when properly used.

You can find a good example here -
[Cross-Domain Messaging With postMessage](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage)

Comment: That would work only if OP can access all the pages (i.e if they can insert the postMessage and onmessage scripts). And this post would greatly beenfit of at least a pseudo-code showing how the end result might be achieved.